# Love2D Menu select

Tags: function, menu, lua, love2d

For some reason the code is not responding when i got the code `if love.keyboard.isDown("s")` Maybe i am using the functions just wrong but its still weird.

I tried using the Menu() function in love.keypressed and in love.update. Still no response.

Here is the full code:

### main.lua

```
function love.load()
require "menu"
select = love.graphics.newImage("select.png")
Menu()
end
function love.draw()
   Menu()
end
function love.keypressed(key)
   Menu()
end

function love.update()
   Menu()
end
```

### menu.lua

```
function Menu()
sly = 300
love.graphics.draw(select,sly,300)
if key == "w" then
    sly = sly + 50
end

if love.keyboard.isDown("s") then
    sly = sly - 50
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do here, but in your `Menu()` function you are resetting the `sly` variable every time you call it, and then modifying `sly` after you have already drawn the image. This results in nothing happening.

If you change it so that `sly` is initialized outside `Menu()`, it at least moves the image when you press the 's' key. Also, if you wanted 's' to move it one way and 'w' to move it the other way, maybe the code should be like this:

```
sly = 300

function Menu()

    love.graphics.draw(select,sly,300)
    if love.keyboard.isDown("w") then
        sly = sly + 50
    end

    if love.keyboard.isDown("s") then
        sly = sly - 50
    end
end
```

Or you could pass the `key` variable into `Menu()` when you call it from `love.keypressed` and not use the `keyboard.isDown` function.

Again, I'm not sure what you are really trying to do here, but it looks to me like the code is working fine, you may just have a logic error.